# Redirect all non-German traffic to english language website?

Tags: redirect, web, traffic

I have a German language website for German traffic from Germany but I would like to redirect all traffic from other countries to a different website. Is that possible? I have already searched on Google but there seems to be nothing. Only redirect certain countries to certain website based on IP but I simply want to redirect all non-German traffic.